# Distribution of $Y$ given $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the numbers on two independent fair-die rolls. Let $X$ be the minimum and $Y$ the maximum of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

$(a)$ Find the distribution of $Y\mid X$

Here is my work:

Here is what I know:

$$P(Y = y\mid X=x) = \frac{P(Y=y, X=x)}{P(X=x)}$$

and $P(X=x)$ can be found by the following equation $\sum_y p_{X,Y}(x,y)$

So here is what I did:

\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
&&&&&y \\
&& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & P(X=x)\\
\hline
&1 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{11}{36} \\
&2 & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{9}{36} \\
x&3 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{7}{36} \\
&4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{5}{36} \\
&5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & \frac{3}{36} \\
&6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{1}{36}
\end{array}

So I said:

$$
P(Y=y\mid X=x) = 
    \begin{cases}
       \frac{1}{36} \div P(X=x) & \text{for } x = y \\[4pt]
       \frac{2}{36} \div P(X=x) & \text{for } x = 1,2,3,4,5,6, \ y > x
    \end{cases}
$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Why write "for $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,\quad y>x$" instead of just writing "for $y>x$"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The conitional probability of A given B is P(AB) / P(B) , so that the sum of conditional probabilities for y with a given x is 1.

Comment: $P(Y=y\mid X=x) =   \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{13-2x}  &  x = y \\ 
 \\
\frac{2}{13-2x} &  x < y & \\
\\
0 & x > y
\end{matrix}\right.  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I said, $$P(Y=y\mid X=x) = 
>     \begin{cases}
>        \frac{1}{36} \cdot P(X=x) & \text{for } x = y \\[4pt]
>        \frac{2}{36} \cdot P(X=x) & \text{for } x = 1,2,3,4,5,6, \ y > x
>     \end{cases}$$
>   Am I correct?

Almost but, *no*.   You know that the conditional probability is the joint divided by the marginal, so *why* did you multiply rather than divide?

Also notice that: $\mathsf P(X=x) = \frac{13-2x}{36}$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid X{=}x) & = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{36} \div P(X=x) & \text{for } x\in\{1\,\ldots\,6\}{\times}\{x\}\\[1ex] \frac{2}{36} \div P(X=x) & \text{for } (x,y)\in \{1\,\ldots\,5\}{\times}\{x{+}1\,\ldots\,6\}  \end{cases} \\[2ex] & = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{13-2x} & \text{for } (x,y)\in\{1\,\ldots\,6\}{\times}\{x\}\\[1ex] \frac{2}{13-2x} & \text{for } (x,y)\in \{1\,\ldots\,5\}{\times}\{x{+}1\,\ldots\,6\}  \end{cases}\end{align}$$

Comment: Yea, the multiply was a typo. I meant to put divide. But your solution makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help